# Memory issues with a very large array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hi I have the following:

```
struct myStructure
{
 vector<int> myVector;
};
myStructure myArray[10000000];
```

As you can see I have a very large array of a vectors. The problem is that i dont have a priori knowledge of the number of elements I need to have in the array, but I know that 10 million elements is the max i can have. I have tried two things:

a) make myArray a global array, however the problem is that i have a function that will access myArray many many times, which is resulting in memory leaks and the program crashing for large calculations.

b) declare myArray dynamically from within the function that needs to access it, the memory is kept in check but the program runs about 8 times slower.

Any ideas on how to address this issue. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, the slow but correct way, or the incorrect but fast way? What a choice! Hint: It's not a choice at all.

Comment: Why you want an array of a `std::vector`, I see a design smell.

Comment: If only there were some kind of dynamic array you could use to hold your vectors.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what the hell are you storing?

Answer (score 3):

> access myArray many many times, which is resulting in memory leaks and the program crashing for large calculations

You should fix those bugs in any case.

> the memory is kept in check but the program runs about 8 times slower

Since you're already using dynamic allocation with an array of vectors it's not immediately obvious why dynamically allocating one more thing would result in such a slowdown. So you should look into this as well.

Then I would go with a `vector<vector<int>>` that isn't global but has the appropriate lifespan for its uses

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using std::vector;

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i) {
        std::for_each(begin(v),end(v),std::mem_fn(&vector<int>::clear));
        foo(v);
        for(int j=0;j<100;++j) {
            std::for_each(begin(v),end(v),std::mem_fn(&vector<int>::clear));
            foo(v);
            for(int k=0;k<100;++k) {
                std::for_each(begin(v),end(v),std::mem_fn(&vector<int>::clear));
                foo(v);
                for(int l=0;l<100;++l) {
                    std::for_each(begin(v),end(v),std::mem_fn(&vector<int>::clear));
                    foo(v);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vector<vector<int>> was slower than using an an array of vectors. I am not sure why.

Comment: How are you using the vector? Do you at some point in the execution know exactly how many vectors myStructure's you'll need? If so, you should call myArray.resize(numElements) when you're using the vector.

Comment: @Jeanno yo might want to try resizing it off the bat in your code if you know a good starting value for how big it will be. This will make it so the vector will have to do a lot less resizing itself, saving you time.

Comment: I think i need to explain a little bit more, the function that accesses and modifies myArray, is called many many times because it is inside a 4 nested loops and it is present at each nesting level. Each call to the function is independent of other calls, it basically uses myStructure to return a variable of type double that is used at each nesting level. With the global approach I have to clear all the vectors right before i exit the function (no need to do that when the array is dynamic). As far as knowing ahead of time the number of elements it is not possible because of multinesting

Comment: @Jeanno define the `vector<vector<int>>` outside of the nested loops and pass a reference to it to each function that needs it. Clear the vector just before or after calling the function. Or maybe it would be better to clear each each vector element, since that would allow you to reuse the storage.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can find is to call the function **"*malloc*"** which reserves space in "heap memory", in the array case you should code something like:

```
int* myArray = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int)* Len );
```

..after that, don't forget to liberate heap memory using free(myArray);
it's a powerful tool to make arrays super large.

Comment: You might want to reread the problem description.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Declare this structure in an object with a lifetime guaranteed to surpass the objects that access it and use a reference to access this object. Ideally, you should have a class in your hierarchy that calls all the functions dealing with this struct, so these functions may well be members of your large array of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turning your array of vectors into a vector of vectors? Not knowing how many of an item you will need is what vectors are for, after all.

I believe it would be

```
vector<vector<int>> myVecs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different data structure.   I'd suggest trying something like one of the 
[sparse matrix classes from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm).  They are optimised for storing numeric data in which each row or column contains a significant number of zeroes.   Mind you, if the problem you're trying to solve isn't suitable for handling with a sparse data structure, it would be a good idea to set out the nature of the problem you're trying to solve, in greater detail.  Take another look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask even though I guess you already read that.

But before you do that I think you probably have another problem too:

> access myArray many many times, which is resulting in memory leaks and 
>   the program crashing for large calculations

It looks to me from what you write there that your code may have some pre-existing bugs.   Unless your crashes are simply caused by trying to allocate a 10000000-element array as an `auto` variable.